# WordPress Custom post type require my file

Tags: wordpress, plugins, require

I am building a plugin that will create a bunch of custom types of posts.
The plugin will connect with an external API for different functions.
For that, the settings page requires the API login form.
All I want is in the admin area, when they will click the custom types pages to be required by the same api login form.
Where should I place the expression

```
<?php require('api_login.php'); ?>
```

for the custom type pages?
Is there a way to make it in the functions?
Please be aware that the plugin will be given away and I will have no control on the other native files of WordPress platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The expression must be in every file where I need to call the login.
Found that later.